# Lottie AnimationView Layer Properties

Tags: ios, swift, animation, lottie

Is it possible to get the Layer Properties out of a Lottie animationView?

Here is a simple example, of what i want to do:

Lottie Animation & UIImage to target

[image: Lottie Animation & UIImage to target]

I have a Lottie Animation (made in After Effects), containing 2 animated Layers – a circle and a star.
I have a moveable UIImageView – with a Target Image assigned.

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// OUTLETS
@IBOutlet weak var lottieView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var targetImage: UIImageView!

var animationView = LOTAnimationView()

func loadAnimation() {
    animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "StackOverflow")
    animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 576)
    animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    animationView.loopAnimation = true
    lottieView.addSubview(animationView)
    animationView.play()
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self.view)

        if targetImage.frame.contains(location) {
            targetImage.center = location
        }

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadAnimation()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

And here is the Code of the StackOVerflow.json-File used in this example:

```
    {  
  "v":"4.10.1",
  "fr":50,
  "ip":0,
  "op":500,
  "w":1024,
  "h":576,
  "nm":"stackOverflowExample",
  "ddd":0,
  "assets":[  

  ],
  "layers":[  
    {  
      "ddd":0,
      "ind":1,
      "ty":4,
      "nm":"Formebene 2",
      "sr":1,
      "ks":{  
        "o":{  
          "a":0,
          "k":100,
          "ix":11
        },
        "r":{  
          "a":0,
          "k":0,
          "ix":10
        },
        "p":{  
          "a":1,
          "k":[  
            {  
              "i":{  
                "x":0.833,
                "y":0.833
              },
              "o":{  
                "x":0.167,
                "y":0.167
              },
              "n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167",
              "t":0,
              "s":[  
                512,
                288,
                0
              ],
              "e":[  
                512,
                465,
                0
              ],
              "to":[  
                0,
                0,
                0
              ],
              "ti":[  
                0,
                0,
                0
              ]
            },
            {  
              "i":{  
                "x":0.833,
                "y":0.833
              },
              "o":{  
                "x":0.167,
                "y":0.167
              },
              "n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167",
              "t":250,
              "s":[  
                512,
                465,
                0
              ],
              "e":[  
                512,
                288,
                0
              ],
              "to":[  
                0,
                0,
                0
              ],
              "ti":[  
                0,
                0,
                0
              ]
            },
            {  
              "t":499
            }
          ],
          "ix":2
        },
        "a":{  
          "a":0,
          "k":[  
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "ix":1
        },
        "s":{  
          "a":0,
          "k":[  
            100,
            100,
            100
          ],
          "ix":6
        }
      },
      "ao":0,
      "shapes":[  
        {  
          "ty":"gr",
          "it":[  
            {  
              "ty":"sr",
              "sy":1,
              "d":1,
              "pt":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":5,
                "ix":3
              },
              "p":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix":4
              },
              "r":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":0,
                "ix":5
              },
              "ir":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":64.322,
                "ix":6
              },
              "is":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":0,
                "ix":8
              },
              "or":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":128.645,
                "ix":7
              },
              "os":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":0,
                "ix":9
              },
              "ix":1,
              "nm":"Sternengruppe-Pfad: 1",
              "mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Star",
              "hd":false
            },
            {  
              "ty":"st",
              "c":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  0.521385043275,
                  0.521385043275,
                  0.521385043275,
                  1
                ],
                "ix":3
              },
              "o":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":100,
                "ix":4
              },
              "w":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":16,
                "ix":5
              },
              "lc":1,
              "lj":1,
              "ml":4,
              "nm":"Kontur 1",
              "mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke",
              "hd":false
            },
            {  
              "ty":"tr",
              "p":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  222.969,
                  -51.672
                ],
                "ix":2
              },
              "a":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix":1
              },
              "s":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  100,
                  100
                ],
                "ix":3
              },
              "r":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":0,
                "ix":6
              },
              "o":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":100,
                "ix":7
              },
              "sk":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":0,
                "ix":4
              },
              "sa":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":0,
                "ix":5
              },
              "nm":"Transformieren"
            }
          ],
          "nm":"Sternengruppe 1",
          "np":3,
          "cix":2,
          "ix":1,
          "mn":"ADBE Vector Group",
          "hd":false
        }
      ],
      "ip":0,
      "op":500,
      "st":0,
      "bm":0
    },
    {  
      "ddd":0,
      "ind":2,
      "ty":4,
      "nm":"Formebene 1",
      "sr":1,
      "ks":{  
        "o":{  
          "a":0,
          "k":100,
          "ix":11
        },
        "r":{  
          "a":0,
          "k":0,
          "ix":10
        },
        "p":{  
          "a":0,
          "k":[  
            512,
            288,
            0
          ],
          "ix":2
        },
        "a":{  
          "a":0,
          "k":[  
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "ix":1
        },
        "s":{  
          "a":0,
          "k":[  
            100,
            100,
            100
          ],
          "ix":6
        }
      },
      "ao":0,
      "shapes":[  
        {  
          "ty":"gr",
          "it":[  
            {  
              "d":1,
              "ty":"el",
              "s":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  216.156,
                  216.156
                ],
                "ix":2
              },
              "p":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix":3
              },
              "nm":"Elliptischer Pfad 1",
              "mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Ellipse",
              "hd":false
            },
            {  
              "ty":"st",
              "c":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  0.521385043275,
                  0.521385043275,
                  0.521385043275,
                  1
                ],
                "ix":3
              },
              "o":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":100,
                "ix":4
              },
              "w":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":16,
                "ix":5
              },
              "lc":1,
              "lj":1,
              "ml":4,
              "d":[  
                {  
                  "n":"d",
                  "nm":"strich",
                  "v":{  
                    "a":0,
                    "k":83,
                    "ix":1
                  }
                },
                {  
                  "n":"g",
                  "nm":"abstand",
                  "v":{  
                    "a":0,
                    "k":14,
                    "ix":2
                  }
                },
                {  
                  "n":"o",
                  "nm":"versatz",
                  "v":{  
                    "a":1,
                    "k":[  
                      {  
                        "i":{  
                          "x":[  
                            0.833
                          ],
                          "y":[  
                            0.833
                          ]
                        },
                        "o":{  
                          "x":[  
                            0.167
                          ],
                          "y":[  
                            0.167
                          ]
                        },
                        "n":[  
                          "0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"
                        ],
                        "t":0,
                        "s":[  
                          -6
                        ],
                        "e":[  
                          -395
                        ]
                      },
                      {  
                        "t":499
                      }
                    ],
                    "ix":7
                  }
                }
              ],
              "nm":"Kontur 1",
              "mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke",
              "hd":false
            },
            {  
              "ty":"tr",
              "p":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  -299.922,
                  -55.922
                ],
                "ix":2
              },
              "a":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix":1
              },
              "s":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":[  
                  100,
                  100
                ],
                "ix":3
              },
              "r":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":0,
                "ix":6
              },
              "o":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":100,
                "ix":7
              },
              "sk":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":0,
                "ix":4
              },
              "sa":{  
                "a":0,
                "k":0,
                "ix":5
              },
              "nm":"Transformieren"
            }
          ],
          "nm":"Ellipse 1",
          "np":3,
          "cix":2,
          "ix":1,
          "mn":"ADBE Vector Group",
          "hd":false
        }
      ],
      "ip":0,
      "op":500,
      "st":0,
      "bm":0
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i want to detect, if the Target Image is overlapping with one of the 2 Layers in the Lottie Animation.

To compare the Target-UIImageView to the position of the shapes in the animation, i need to access the Layer Properties (frame or position) in the Lottie animationView.

I haven't found anything in the Lottie-Documentation – so I am not sure if it even is possible. Does somebody know if this is possible?

How do i access the Layer Properties inside of a Lottie Animation?